# React app is not updating on web server after git pull

Tags: reactjs, git, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I have deployed a react application using this tutorial on Medium:

https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7

I am using an Ubuntu server from Digital Ocean.

It worked perfect for deploying the web app by doing "git pull" in the /var/www-folder.

However, I am not able to change the app running on the server. When I change the repo locally, git push locally and pull on the remote server, everything seems to be working fine. With "git log" I can see that the changes to the repo are actually registered. However, after running

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

The changes are not visible on the server when I go the the corresponding IP-adress..
I even tried building the project after pulling on the server.

What could the solution to this be?
Thanks:)

Comment: Website could be cached. Did you try to clear the cache and reload the site?

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried it now but did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Jayce444 do you mean the cache in the webbrowser or ngnix cache?

Comment: I meant in the web browser. I don't know much about nginx, but does restarting that service actually restart the _process_ that's serving your webapp? For example, if you were serving your app with an Express server, you'd need to restart that Express server so that it starts hosting the new content. Does your nginx restart command do that?