# I can't update changes in a react app which is on prod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, ubuntu, nginx

I've made some changes on a simple landing with React, which is placed in a NGINX server. After done pull from repo and see the report from git that show how the changes has been carried out satisfactorily. I don't notice any change when I go to the corresponding domain, I've tried the following steps:

1. I've removed and rebuild the statics files with command `npm run build`
2. I've verified and there was no directory nginx in the path `var/cache/nginx`
3. I've cleared the cache in my browser
4. I restarted the NGINX server
5. I've removed all the project and clone it again from 0. And it continue showing the last version of the web

Seeking, I found an other post with the same problem [React app is not updating on web server after git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514898/react-app-is-not-updating-on-web-server-after-git-pull), but nobody gave any solution.

To be honest I don't use to work with React, Does anyone come up with something? Thanks you very much.

Comment: if you stop your nginx server, is your website still functioning?
Besides, did you check if proper `location` and `root` is setup on: this location: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_domain` ?

Comment: besides, did you copy your `build` or `dist` folder, after building to the nginx's required location? For example, after `npm run build` you would do: `mv ./build/* <nginx root, i.e. /var/www/your_domain/html>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I answer u step by step: 1) if I stop NGINX service the website stop working 2) I've verified that root it's the owner of the conf and that both exists in sites-enabled and sites-avalible

Comment: in /var/www/my_domain/build is created by a symbolic link from /home/ubuntu/projects/my_domain

Comment: It's ok I'm idiot inside var/www/my_domain/ was the previous build I forgot to copy al new rebuild and paste it there :/, Sorry and big thank you to you

Comment: awesome, glad I could help!